# Seeking global map projection centered on Americas

Tags: coordinate-system, antimeridian

I currently use EPSG: 4326.

How can I re-project the map so that the blue delineation appears as one continuum, rather than being split into a western and eastern component?

[image]

EPSG:3832:

[image]

Comment: https://www.gislounge.com/center-map-pacific-ocean-using-qgis/

Comment: Have you tried re-projecting to EPSG:3832 as shown Here: https://www.gislounge.com/center-map-pacific-ocean-using-qgis/

Comment: Thanks for this helpful suggestions. I do find though that part of South America is no longer in the map. Ideally, I would like to display the entirety of North and South America. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: I've noticed this thread doesn't seem to have a satisfactory answer other than "Just download the only available America-centric projection". It took me some finding, but this other SE thread will show you how to recenter ANY projection ANYWHERE you want. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447123/recenter-projection-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EPSG:8858` WGS 84 / Equal Earth Americas. The use case for this projection is [described as follows](https://epsg.io/8858):

> Very small scale equal-area mapping - Americas-centred.

[image]