# Recenter projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, center

I'm new here, using QGIS 3.26.3. I have limited experience with GIS (mainly Global Mapper). I've also used QGIS before, but only to view data. I've used Global Mapper to make maps, including re-projecting and re-centering without any difficulty. But QGIS defeats me every time I try to re-center a projection. I've tried editing the .prj file, but that doesn't work, and I can't find an option in QGIS to specify the center. I'm trying to recenter an orthographic projection of the whole world. How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Are you asking about how to change the centre point of an orthographic projection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you're trying to change the projection point of an orthographic projection. Unfortunately, QGIS doesn't have a GUI for projection options, so it has to be done manually:

1. Open the "Custom Projections" windows from toolbar > settings

[image: 1]

2. Keep the format as "Proj string" and in the parameters box type the following:

`+proj=ortho +lat_0=LATITUDE +lon_0=LONGTIDUE`

replacing LATITUDE and LONGITUDE with the respective values. For example, for Australia:

`+proj=ortho +lat_0=-23.4 +lon_0=135.1`

3. Press "Ok" to save your projection and leave the window.
4. At the bottom right, click on the spherical icon which should have some text preceded by `EPSG:`

[image]

5. Scroll to the bottom of the "Predefined coordinate systems" segment until you find "User Defined Coordinate Systems". Uncollapse this with the arrow and select your custom coordinate system.`

If all goes well you should have a result similar to this:

[image]

---

- `+proj=ortho` defines the orthographic projection
- `+lat_0=<latitude>` defines the latitude
- `+lon_0=<longitude>` defines the longitude
- `+R=` allows you to change the radius of the ellipsoid

[Here](https://proj.org/operations/projections/ortho.html) you can find a helpful explanation of the relevant and additional parameters for the `ortho` projection.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will try that when I get back home.

Comment: #anotheranalyst This worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Craig, marking it as "correct" with the tick would be helpful :) Happy to help!

Comment: @user183939 Thanks for the tip about the flag. Thanks again for your help. QGIS is a mystery to me, but starting to develop some knowledge/skills.