# Raster crossing anti meridian in QGIS

Tags: qgis, epsg, utm, antimeridian

See the raster overlayed in QGIS below:

[image: .tiff overlayed in QGIS, UTM zone 32760]

I am trying to project a GeoTiff in QGIS that crosses the anti meridian, but the area circled in red in the above picture is exactly 180/-180, so there is some odd line going on there. Is there any way I can work around this? I just need the GeoTiff to not look broken, which it currently does because of that section at exactly 180/-180

In my application I generate the GeoTiff using lat/long values, the centre point of the bounding box is -16.755917, 179.916913, and it spans 100km in each direction (north, east, south, west) from that centre point, so part of the GeoTiff crosses the anti meridian. Internally, I believe my code works and can handle crossing the anti meridian, as I can see terrain on the anti meridian side being shown, it's just that point at literally 180/-180 that looks odd and I need to fix.

I project my GeoTiff from lat/long values to UTM (in this case, zone 32760), and it is overlaid on the OpenStreetMap layer in UTM zone 32760.

Side note: is it normal for QGIS to hang/freeze/constantly buffer when the zoomed area crosses the anti meridian? as you can see in the screenshot, the coordinates spanning from -180 downwards are in white, and I can't get OpenStreetMaps to render that part. It would be a big help if that area actually rendered so I can compare my GeoTiff to what the actual terrain looks like.

Comment: EPSG:32760 doesn't cross the anti-meridian so that is probably not helping - see if https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426070/seeking-global-map-projection-centered-on-americas helps